# Secure connect Power BI Desktop to PostgreSQL localhost

Tags: postgresql, encryption, powerbi

I want to connect a localhost PostgreSQL database with Power BI Desktop. I know how to do it, but I have a question regarding a secure connection. When trying to connect a window pops up saying... ***Encryption Support*** We were unable to connect to the data source using an encrypted connection... My question is, how to ensure a encrypted connection with my localhost PostgreSQL database?